# SSH with domain instead of IP address

Tags: ssh, dns, ubuntu-16.04, linode

I have a ubuntu 16.04 @ linode.com.

I wanna be able to login through a subdomain (master.mydomainname.com) instead of an IP (192.0.2.1).

```
> hostname
domainname_master

> cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1     localhost
127.0.1.1     ubuntu.members.linode.com ubuntu
192.0.2.1     master.mydomainname.com mydomainname_master
```

I have a working A & AAAA record subdomain at cloudflare, which reachable through a webbrowser (nginx)

but when I try

```
root@master.mydomainname.com
```

I cant connect: 
    ssh: connect to host master.mydomainname.com port 22: No route to host

With the IP itself I have no troubles to connect via SSH.

Did I miss something?

Comment: Your example might be too obfuscated.  `123.456.789` is not even close to an IP address (it's missing the fourth decimal and two of the three it does have are larger than the maximum of 255).

Comment: changed it in my post

Comment: it is only a "dummy ip" because I don't wanna show my own...

Comment: I've edited the question to fix your dummy IP and made the hostname more consistent.  The new IP used above is part of the TEST-NET [reserved IP space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reserved_IP_addresses).

Comment: Is the subdomain part of the site? An address you want visitors to use? If not, it should be the FQDN of the server and not routed through CloudFlare (DNS only) which would allow port 22 access for SSH.

Comment: Make sure your domain is mapped on that IP which is accessible !!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend doing this in `/etc/hosts` unless you have other reasons to do so.  Instead, I'd recommend editing `~/.ssh/config` (or a new file in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config.d` for all users) to add an entry to make this work for anything that uses SSH with your account (including `scp`, `sftp`, and `rsync` among others).

```sh
Host master master.mydomainname.com mydomainname_master
  Hostname 192.0.2.1
  User root
```

This content in your config file (learn more with [`man ssh_config`](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config)) will allow you to run `ssh master` or `ssh master.mydomainname.com` or `ssh mydomainname_master` without needing to specify the host IP or even the username (root) on the command line.  You always override the username by running e.g. `ssh jan@master`

(If you're installing this system-wide, you probably don't want to specify the username.)